# Service to Geocode Chinese Addresses?

Tags: geocoding, geocoding-service

What geocoding service can handle addresses in China and deliver accurate latitude, longitude, and estimation of accuracy results?  I have between 6,000 and 40,000 addresses in total.

Comment: This seems like a perfectly good question to me, but the community on this site *really* doesn't like questions with the word "best" in them, so your question is probably about to be put on hold. May I suggest re-wording it like "what geocoding services work in China" or similar.

Comment: Can it be online?  Have you tried this? https://geocode.xyz/CN